# Jade mixin attributes not applied

Tags: javascript, pug

I'm using jade to template a report table as follows:

```
mixin report_row(row)
  tr(data-id=row.c[keyIndex].v)
    each cell, i in row.c
      +cell_decorator(data.cols[i], cell)(data-foo="bar")
```

It's a nested mixin structure for a report row comprised of decorated report cells.

The problem is that the data-foo attribute is not being applied.

I've seen other issues on SO about mixin attributes but I cannot find any syntax issue with the template, it just renders while ignoring the attributes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/) shows an example of passing attributes to mixins:

```
mixin link(href, name)
  //- attributes == {class: "btn"}
  a(class!=attributes.class, href=href)= name

+link('/foo', 'foo')(class="btn")
```

Notice that the mixin itself uses the implicit `attributes` name to refer to the passed attributes - in other words, the attributes aren't auto-applied, they are just sent as arguments into the mixin. You'll have to change the definition of your `cell_decorator` mixin to take the attributes into account.

If you want to simply apply the attributes on top of your mixin, you can use the [`&attributes`](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes) syntax:

```
mixin cell_decorator(colname, data)
    //- the `attributes` get applied to the td
    td(...)&attributes(attributes)

+cell_decorator(data.cols[i], cell)(data-foo="bar")
```

Note that using `&attributes` like this (with a mixin call) is safe, as the values are escaped during the call.

Comment: You're totally right, I completely missed the attribute application. Thanks @voithos !